# ActivatedRoute.snapshot.url doesn't have the first part of url in angular with multiple modules. How can I access to full URL?

Tags: angular, url, snapshot, angular-activatedroute

I have three modules in angular (AppModule, ProductsModule and OrdersModule) with below configuration.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'products', loadChildren: () => import('./products/products.module').then(
          m => m.ProductsModule) },
  { path: 'orders', loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(
          m => m.OrdersModule) },
];
```

In components of these modules, ActivatedRoute.snapshot.url does not have the first part of url (i.e. 'products' or 'orders'). How can I access to full URL?

Comment: Did you try looking at the firstChild: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#firstChild

Comment: Yes. but this doesn't work. But I use  ActivatedRoute.snapshot.pathFromRoot and it works. thank you

Comment: You're welcome, you can either write your own answer or just delete this.